# I have a main method but still get an error

Tags: java, string, program-entry-point, args

I am trying to write a simple program below.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.printIn("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

I saved the file as "HelloWorld.java" and I navigated to the directory and typed in this command in my terminal `javac HelloWorld.java`. This created a HelloWorld.class file. I then typed in `java HelloWorld` in my terminal to run the file and I get this error

> "Error: Main method not found in class HelloWorld, please define the main method as:
>   public static void main(String[] args)
>   or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application"

So the error message is telling me I don't have a main method inside the class, I have tried a capital M and lowercase m and I would still get the same error. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: have you save the file?

Comment: This does not compile. The method `printIn` does not exist. It should be `println` (lowercase "L", not uppercase "I"). Fixing the typo works as expected

Answer (score 1):

You needed a lowercase "L" not an upcase "I". If it helps to remember "println" stands for "print line".

```
// Copy and paste this to correct your error.
System.out.println("Hello, World");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a wrong spelling

```
//System.out.printIn("Hello, World");
System.out.println("Hello, World");
```

you wrote a capital `"I"` instead of small `"L"`